# Problem booting ubuntu after uninstalling KDE

Tags: boot, gnome, kde, gdm, tty

Whenever I boot my ubuntu system it goes into tty mode, there is no gui.

Every time I boot I have to use `startx` in tty to access my desktop.
I installed KDE plasma a long time ago without deleting gnome. Then I switched back to gnome by following the instruction on [this site](https://trendoceans.com/how-to-remove-the-kde-plasma-environment-in-ubuntu/)

I tried following the instructions on [this forum](https://superuser.com/questions/65185/when-i-start-ubuntu-it-enters-tty1-6-instead-of-my-desktop-how-do-i-get-to-de) to solve this problem.

If I run the command `which gdm` nothing shows up
and If I run `ls etc/init.d | grep gdm` it says no such file or directory

But if I run `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` it shows `/usr/sbin/gdm3`

`Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic`

Help me.

Comment: Changing the DE on an installed system can be extremely messy. This is why Ubuntu developers spend so much effort on releasing and maintaining 9 distinct desktop [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours). It's recommended for users to choose the DE before system installation. With that in mind, if you'd still like to troubleshoot your current system, you will likely need to provide more details about the full history of your installation as well as more details about the problem you are experiencing as well as the details of attempts to fix it. I recommend you reinstall.

Comment: What do these say? `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart` `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` `ls /etc/init.d | grep gdm` You seem to be mentioning etc instead of /etc.
Just to be sure. May be you have a typo in other configurations as well.